# Deixar a barra lateral fixa depois de abrir

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, bootstrap

Estou montando um quebra cabeça em bootstrap, e quase deu certo o que preciso. Vou usar esse modelo somente no mobile.

Faltou só deixar a menu lateral (Toggle Menu) fixo depois de abrir. Tentei por css mas não consegui.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Simple Sidebar - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
 <style type="text/css">
body{ /* for demo purpose only */
    /* height:2000px;
    padding-top:100px; */
} 
 </style>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top " role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
   <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
      <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a> -->
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>






    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">
                        Start Bootstrap
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>
                        <p>Nam quis nulla. Integer malesuada. In in enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. Sed vel lectus. Donec odio urna, tempus molestie, porttitor ut, iaculis quis, sem. Phasellus rhoncus. Aenean id metus id velit ullamcorper pulvinar. Vestibulum fermentum tortor id mi. Pellentesque ipsum. Nulla non arcu lacinia neque faucibus fringilla. Nulla non lectus sed nisl molestie malesuada. Proin in tellus sit amet nibh dignissim sagittis. Vivamus luctus egestas leo. Maecenas sollicitudin. Nullam rhoncus aliquam metus. Etiam egestas wisi a erat.

 Nam quis nulla. Integer malesuada. In in enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. Sed vel lectus. Donec odio urna, tempus molestie, porttitor ut, iaculis quis, sem. Phasellus rhoncus. Aenean id metus id velit ullamcorper pulvinar. Vestibulum fermentum tortor id mi. Pellentesque ipsum. Nulla non arcu lacinia neque faucibus fringilla. Nulla non lectus sed nisl molestie malesuada. Proin in tellus sit amet nibh dignissim sagittis. Vivamus luctus egestas leo. Maecenas sollicitudin. Nullam rhoncus aliquam metus. Etiam egestas wisi a erat.

 Morbi leo mi, nonummy eget, tristique non, rhoncus non, leo. Nullam faucibus mi quis velit. Integer in sapien. Fusce tellus odio, dapibus id, fermentum quis, suscipit id, erat. Fusce aliquam vestibulum ipsum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque sapien. Cras elementum. Nulla pulvinar eleifend sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Quisque porta. Vivamus porttitor turpis ac leo.

 Aenean placerat. In vulputate urna eu arcu. Aliquam erat volutpat. Suspendisse potenti. Morbi mattis felis at nunc. Duis viverra diam non justo. In nisl. Nullam sit amet magna in magna gravida vehicula. Mauris tincidunt sem sed arcu. Nunc posuere. Nullam lectus justo, vulputate eget, mollis sed, tempor sed, magna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam neque. Curabitur ligula sapien, pulvinar a, vestibulum quis, facilisis vel, sapien. Nullam eget nisl. Donec vitae arcu.

 Aenean placerat. In vulputate urna eu arcu. Aliquam erat volutpat. Suspendisse potenti. Morbi mattis felis at nunc. Duis viverra diam non justo. In nisl. Nullam sit amet magna in magna gravida vehicula. Mauris tincidunt sem sed arcu. Nunc posuere. Nullam lectus justo, vulputate eget, mollis sed, tempor sed, magna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam neque. Curabitur ligula sapien, pulvinar a, vestibulum quis, facilisis vel, sapien. Nullam eget nisl. Donec vitae arcu.

 Aenean placerat. In vulputate urna eu arcu. Aliquam erat volutpat. Suspendisse potenti. Morbi mattis felis at nunc. Duis viverra diam non justo. In nisl. Nullam sit amet magna in magna gravida vehicula. Mauris tincidunt sem sed arcu. Nunc posuere. Nullam lectus justo, vulputate eget, mollis sed, tempor sed, magna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam neque. Curabitur ligula sapien, pulvinar a, vestibulum quis, facilisis vel, sapien. Nullam eget nisl. Donec vitae arcu.

 Morbi a metus. Phasellus enim erat, vestibulum vel, aliquam a, posuere eu, velit. Nullam sapien sem, ornare ac, nonummy non, lobortis a, enim. Nunc tincidunt ante vitae massa. Duis ante orci, molestie vitae, vehicula venenatis, tincidunt ac, pede. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Donec iaculis gravida nulla. Donec quis nibh at felis congue commodo. Etiam bibendum elit eget erat.

 Etiam posuere quam ac quam. Maecenas aliquet accumsan leo. Nullam dapibus fermentum ipsum. Etiam quis quam. Integer lacinia. Nulla est. Nulla turpis magna, cursus sit amet, suscipit a, interdum id, felis. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Maecenas lorem. Pellentesque pretium lectus id turpis. Etiam sapien elit, consequat eget, tristique non, venenatis quis, ante. Fusce wisi. Phasellus faucibus molestie nisl. Fusce eget urna. Curabitur vitae diam non enim vestibulum interdum. Nulla quis diam. Ut tempus purus at lorem.

 Nam quis nulla. Integer malesuada. In in enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. Sed vel lectus. Donec odio urna, tempus molestie, porttitor ut, iaculis quis, sem. Phasellus rhoncus. Aenean id metus id velit ullamcorper pulvinar. Vestibulum fermentum tortor id mi. Pellentesque ipsum. Nulla non arcu lacinia neque faucibus fringilla. Nulla non lectus sed nisl molestie malesuada. Proin in tellus sit amet nibh dignissim sagittis. Vivamus luctus egestas leo. Maecenas sollicitudin. Nullam rhoncus aliquam metus. Etiam egestas wisi a erat.

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi gravida libero nec velit. Morbi scelerisque luctus velit. Etiam dui sem, fermentum vitae, sagittis id, malesuada in, quam. Proin mattis lacinia justo. Vestibulum facilisis auctor urna. Aliquam in lorem sit amet leo accumsan lacinia. Integer rutrum, orci vestibulum ullamcorper ultricies, lacus quam ultricies odio, vitae placerat pede sem sit amet enim. Phasellus et lorem id felis nonummy placerat. Fusce dui leo, imperdiet in, aliquam sit amet, feugiat eu, orci. Aenean vel massa quis mauris vehicula lacinia. Quisque tincidunt scelerisque libero. Maecenas libero. Etiam dictum tincidunt diam. Donec ipsum massa, ullamcorper in, auctor et, scelerisque sed, est. Suspendisse nisl. Sed convallis magna eu sem. Cras pede libero, dapibus nec, pretium sit amet, tempor quis, urna.

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam feugiat, turpis at pulvinar vulputate, erat libero tristique tellus, nec bibendum odio risus sit amet ante. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc auctor. Mauris pretium quam et urna. Fusce nibh. Duis risus. Curabitur sagittis hendrerit ante. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum erat nulla, ullamcorper nec, rutrum non, nonummy ac, erat. Duis condimentum augue id magna semper rutrum. Nullam justo enim, consectetuer nec, ullamcorper ac, vestibulum in, elit. Proin pede metus, vulputate nec, fermentum fringilla, vehicula vitae, justo. Fusce consectetuer risus a nunc. Aliquam ornare wisi eu metus. Integer pellentesque quam vel velit. Duis pulvinar.

 Aenean placerat. In vulputate urna eu arcu. Aliquam erat volutpat. Suspendisse potenti. Morbi mattis felis at nunc. Duis viverra diam non justo. In nisl. Nullam sit amet magna in magna gravida vehicula. Mauris tincidunt sem sed arcu. Nunc posuere. Nullam lectus justo, vulputate eget, mollis sed, tempor sed, magna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam neque. Curabitur ligula sapien, pulvinar a, vestibulum quis, facilisis vel, sapien. Nullam eget nisl. Donec vitae arcu.

 Maecenas ipsum velit, consectetuer eu, lobortis ut, dictum at, dui. In rutrum. Sed ac dolor sit amet purus malesuada congue. In laoreet, magna id viverra tincidunt, sem odio bibendum justo, vel imperdiet sapien wisi sed libero. Suspendisse sagittis ultrices augue. Mauris metus. Nunc dapibus tortor vel mi dapibus sollicitudin. Etiam posuere lacus quis dolor. Praesent id justo in neque elementum ultrices. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. In convallis. Fusce suscipit libero eget elit. Praesent vitae arcu tempor neque lacinia pretium. Morbi imperdiet, mauris ac auctor dictum, nisl ligula egestas nulla, et sollicitudin sem purus in lacus.

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi gravida libero nec velit. Morbi scelerisque luctus velit. Etiam dui sem, fermentum vitae, sagittis id, malesuada in, quam. Proin mattis lacinia justo. Vestibulum facilisis auctor urna. Aliquam in lorem sit amet leo accumsan lacinia. Integer rutrum, orci vestibulum ullamcorper ultricies, lacus quam ultricies odio, vitae placerat pede sem sit amet enim. Phasellus et lorem id felis nonummy placerat. Fusce dui leo, imperdiet in, aliquam sit amet, feugiat eu, orci. Aenean vel massa quis mauris vehicula lacinia. Quisque tincidunt scelerisque libero. Maecenas libero. Etiam dictum tincidunt diam. Donec ipsum massa, ullamcorper in, auctor et, scelerisque sed, est. Suspendisse nisl. Sed convallis magna eu sem. Cras pede libero, dapibus nec, pretium sit amet, tempor quis, urna.

 Maecenas ipsum velit, consectetuer eu, lobortis ut, dictum at, dui. In rutrum. Sed ac dolor sit amet purus malesuada congue. In laoreet, magna id viverra tincidunt, sem odio bibendum justo, vel imperdiet sapien wisi sed libero. Suspendisse sagittis ultrices augue. Mauris metus. Nunc dapibus tortor vel mi dapibus sollicitudin. Etiam posuere lacus quis dolor. Praesent id justo in neque elementum ultrices. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. In convallis. Fusce suscipit libero eget elit. Praesent vitae arcu tempor neque lacinia pretium. Morbi imperdiet, mauris ac auctor dictum, nisl ligula egestas nulla, et sollicitudin sem purus in lacus.

 </p>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->


    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    
 // hide .navbar first
 $(".navbar").hide();
 
 // fade in .navbar
 $(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function () {
            // set distance user needs to scroll before we fadeIn navbar
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('.navbar').fadeIn();
   } else {
    $('.navbar').fadeOut();
   }
  });

 
 });

});
  }(jQuery));
    </script>

 
    <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
    </script> 
 
 
</body>

</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou fazer com javascript? Talvez adicionando e removendo uma classe CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução seria adicionar a classe através do jQuery.

```
$("#sidebar-wrapper").click(function() {
         $(this).addClass("fixed");  
});
```

E no CSS adicionar uma classe com position fixed.

```
fixed {
    position:fixed;
}
```